# To get the count of this month's entries in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, datetime, sequelize.js

i have used postgresql database with createdAt column type as timestamp with timezone.

i want to filter the entries for the current month

```
Example.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: [Sequelize.fn("date_trunc", "month", Sequelize.col("createdAt"))]
  }
});
```

i have tried the above code but that returns 0 even the entries are there for current month,i wanted to get the entries that has been made from the start of the month to till now , and that has to be dynamically work for every month .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no expert at sequelize but where are you passing the month and year you want the result for?? Something like this should work: `[Op.and]: [ { createdAt: { [Op.gte]: '2021-12-01' } }, { createdAt: { [Op.lte]: '2021-12-31' } }, ]` or try `[Op.between]` instead of `[Op.and]` You can obviously change `'2021-12-31'` to whatever you need.

Comment: Hi , I'm not passing a particular month or year..i wanted the function to get the current month from a new Date() and to compare with the "createdAt" to get the result.. and i wanted it to happen for every month without giving the date manually , can u suggest any way to make '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31' as a dynamic? Thanks .

Comment: Simplest way to do this is using moment.js or day.js library to format the date, for example using day.js first day of month `dayjs().date(1).format('yyyy-MM-dd')` and for the last day of month `dayjs().date(dayjs().daysInMonth()).format('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: Hi, Thank u so much.. it works